# How to extract the source code for HTML Form Web Part in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, html-form-web-part

I wanna edit the page of SP 2010 site pages' using SP DESIGNER  2010 tool. But when I opened the page, I am able to see only the page layouts.
I am unable to see the web parts' contents -lie div tag, html elements etc.

How to extract the contents of the already existing HTML FORM web part within a  site page? Due to some reason, i am unable to open the source editor from the UI/browser.

I tried with `?contents=2` in the browser and `?toolpaneview=2` but, it didnt give the source of the html form web part.
How to extract the source code?

Answer (score 2):

Go to All Files from left navigation. check if you find your Site pages library there and open it from there, If not check under _catalogs folder.